# What does renv::activate() do?

Tags: r, renv

I read [here in the documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/activate.html) that `renv::activate()` adds `source("renv/init.R")` to the project .Rprofile. However, my .Rprofile has `source("renv/activate.R")` in there instead, as created by RStudio.

Isn't this an error in de documentation? It does not make sense to call `renv::init()` every time you open an RStudio project, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks -- that is an error in the documentation, the script is indeed located at `renv/activate.R`.

To clarify, the main job of `renv::activate()` (and the related function `renv::deactivate()`) is to just add or remove the `renv` auto-loader from the project `.Rprofile`, which ensures that newly-launched R sessions in that `renv` is automatically activated in that project (so that the project-local library is used, etc.)